# How to play back a array of samples after reading them from an 'ISampleSource'

Tags: c#, cscore

So, I have a piece of code that reads out an `ISampleSource` in to a `float[][]`, the first array layer being for the number of channels and the second being for the sample data within the channel. I am going to take this data and attempt to apply signal processing to it, however for debugging purposes I might want to manipulate the sample array and then play it back so that I can "hear" what the code is doing. is there an easy way to take the data returned by `ISampleSource.Read` and stick it back in to a *new* `ISampleSource` so it can then be converted to an `IWaveSource` and played using `WasapiOut`?

Here is the class I tried to make so far, you pass it the `float[][]` and basically all the data in a `WaveFormat` for it to make one from.. but it doesn't actually do *anything*. doesn't error, doesn't play.. just does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
private class SampleSource : ISampleSource
{
    public long Position { get; set; }
    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }
    public bool CanSeek => true;
    public long Length  => _data.Length;

    private float[] _data;
    private long readPoint = 0;

    public SampleSource(float[][] samples, int sampleRate, int bits, int channels)
    {
        WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(sampleRate, bits, channels);
        if (samples.Length <= 0) return;

        _data = new float[samples[0].Length * samples.Length];
        int cchannels = samples.Length;
        int sampleLength = samples[0].Length;

        for (var i = 0; i < sampleLength; i += cchannels)
            for (var n = 0; n < cchannels; n++)
                _data[i + n] = samples[n][i / cchannels];
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (_data.Length < Position + count)
            count = (int) (_data.Length - Position);

        float[] outFloats = new float[count];
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            outFloats[i] = _data[i + Position + offset];

        buffer = outFloats;
        Position += count;
        return count;
    }

    public void Dispose() =>_data = null;
}
```

Comment: It may sound stupid, but it's common, did you turned on volume, or plugged audio players?

Comment: Yes, for the sake of sanity I have been playing a non-toyed with "raw" `ISampleSource` that plays fine, I then load the same file to a different `ISampleSource`, do my process to extract the channel data, then put it in to this class I've created. All I get in the output is a message for a thread terminating as soon as I call `play`.

Comment: Isn't there thrown any exception??

Comment: Nope, no errors, no indication of anything.

Comment: Did you lunched your program in debug mode?? Any information why thread is terminated, there?

Comment: Yes I always run in Debug mode.. no. there's no information, no indication of anything as I said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173650/discussion-between-kacper-and-james-trotter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to set `buffer` to a new array (which makes no sense) I needed to directly write to the `buffer` array elements, so that they can be used outside of the function call. I don't really *like* doing it this way, maybe it's to fix an issue I don't see, but clearly that's how the library I'm using does it.

```
private class SampleSource : ISampleSource
{
    public long Position { get; set; }
    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }
    public bool CanSeek => true;
    public long Length  => _data.Length;

    private float[] _data;
    private long readPoint = 0;

    public SampleSource(float[][] samples, int sampleRate, int bits, int channels)
    {
        WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(sampleRate, bits, channels);
        if (samples.Length <= 0) return;

        _data = new float[samples[0].Length * samples.Length];
        int cchannels = samples.Length;
        int sampleLength = samples[0].Length;

        for (var i = 0; i < sampleLength; i += cchannels)
            for (var n = 0; n < cchannels; n++)
                _data[i + n] = samples[n][i / cchannels];
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        /*THIS IS THE CHANGED FUNCTION*/
        if (_data.Length < Position + count)
            count = (int) (_data.Length - Position);

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            buffer[i] = _data[i + Position + offset];

        Position += count;
        return count;
    }

    public void Dispose() =>_data = null;
}
```